# Снятие фокуса с EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

В общем, курсор в `EditText` светится всегда. Как сделать, чтобы он светился только тогда, когда я нажимаю на `EditText` и пишу в нем что-то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

убрать атрибут <requestFocus /> 
и добавить в xml это

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Comment: теперь при открытии активити с едиттексами, курсор по умолчанию не мигает. когда нажимаю - мигает, при клике в другое место он всеравно остается мигать...

Comment: У меня работает нормально. Я к родительскому LinearLayout добавил указанный код.

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Как-то так:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="false" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: requestFocus работает только с одним EditText. А у меня их несколько.

Comment: Это решение убирает просто курсор с EditText, но он все равно выбран. В этом можно убедиться, если использовать FloatingLabels, так что я бы назвал это плохим решением.